# Parsing text from XML node in Python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I'm trying to extract URLs from a sitemap like this: https://www.bestbuy.com/sitemap_c_0.xml.gz

I've unzipped and saved the .xml.gz file as an .xml file. The structure looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<url>
    <loc>https://www.bestbuy.com/</loc>
    <priority>0.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://www.bestbuy.com/site/3d-printers/3d-printer-filament/pcmcat335400050008.c?id=pcmcat335400050008</loc>
    <priority>0.0</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://www.bestbuy.com/site/3d-printers/3d-printing-accessories/pcmcat748300527647.c?id=pcmcat748300527647</loc>
    <priority>0.0</priority>
</url>
```

I'm attempting to use ElementTree to extract all of the URLs within the **loc** nodes throughout this file, but struggling to get it working right.

Per the documentation, I'm trying something like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('my_local_filepath')
root = tree.getroot()

value = root.findall(".//loc")
```

However, nothing gets loaded into value. My goal is to extract all of the URLs between the loc nodes and print it out into a new flat file. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are not taking namespaces into account. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can iterate through the URLs, toss them into a list and write them to a file as such:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

name_space = '{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}'

urls = []
for child in root.iter():
    for block in child.findall('{}url'.format(name_space)):
        for url in block.findall('{}loc'.format(name_space)):
            urls.append('{}\n'.format(url.text))

with open('sample_urls.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.writelines(urls)
```

- note we need to append the name space from the open urlset definition to properly parse the xml

Comment: It doesn't work, my urls array is still empty. Not sure if there's a formatting issue with the actual XML file I'm trying to open? I'm scraping the .xml.gz file like the one I linked to and using GzipFile to unzip it.

Comment: Right, I think I chopped some important info off with my test file, and appending it in the parsing should help. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You were close in your attempt but like mzjn said in a comment, you didn't account for the default namespace (`xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"`).

Here's an example of how to account for the namespace:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('my_local_filepath')

ns = {"sm": "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"}

for elem in tree.findall(".//sm:loc", ns):
    print(elem.text)
```

output:

```
https://www.bestbuy.com/
https://www.bestbuy.com/site/3d-printers/3d-printer-filament/pcmcat335400050008.c?id=pcmcat335400050008
https://www.bestbuy.com/site/3d-printers/3d-printing-accessories/pcmcat748300527647.c?id=pcmcat748300527647
```

Note that I used the namespace prefix `sm`, but you could use any [NCName](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#ns-decl).

[See here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces) for more information on parsing XML with namespaces in ElementTree.