# Root element confusion using ElementTree

Tags: python-3.x, elementtree

I'm using ElementTree in Python 3.5.1. I want to parse a xml file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>A name</name>
    <groupId>a.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>anArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <dependency-version>10.0</dependency-version>
        <another-dependency-version>11.0</another-dependency-version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

And get the value of the tag **dependency-version**. I started trying to get the **properties** using this code:

```
mydoc = ElementTree.parse(sources + "pom.xml")
root = mydoc.getroot()
for element in root.findall('properties'):
    print(element)
```

The issue is that I got nothing but the root tag, **project**, and its attributes.

```
>>> root.tag
'{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}project'
>>> root.text
'\n    '
>>> root.attrib
{'{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}schemaLocation': 'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd'}
```

I tried also with mydoc directly:

```
>>> root.findall('project')
[]
>>> mydoc.findall('./properties')
[]
>>> mydoc.findall('./project/properties') 
[]
```

I understood that *getroot()* will give me the project tag and from there I can start working, but seems I got something wrong.

**EDIT**

I followed the proposed solution and I got:

```
>>> ns
{'sm': 'http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0'}
>>> mydoc.findall('.//sm:properties', ns)
[<Element '{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}properties' at 0x0325AA80>]
>>> root.findall('.//sm:properties', ns)
[<Element '{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}properties' at 0x0325AA80>]
>>> mydoc.findall('.//sm:properties/dependency-version', ns)
[]
```

Seems is finding something now, but not the two elements of the tag **properties**

Comment: It's because you're not taking the default namespace (`http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0`) into account. See my answer here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52864678/317052

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing text from XML node in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52847343/parsing-text-from-xml-node-in-python)

Comment: I got a different solution removing the namespaces.

Comment: Please don't add solutions in the question. Post a proper answer instead. You can accept your own answer.

Comment: `mydoc.findall('.//sm:properties/sm:dependency-version', ns)` works. The prefix must be used on all elements.

Comment: Yes, that worked also, thanks! I have not thought on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I got an idea from: [Python ElementTree module: How to ignore the namespace of XML files to locate matching element when using the method "find", "findall"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412496/python-elementtree-module-how-to-ignore-the-namespace-of-xml-files-to-locate-ma)
What is, basically, get rid of the namespaces.

```
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElementTree

filestring = open("C:/temp/test.xml", "r").read()
xmlwithoutns = re.sub('<project[^>]+', '<project>', filestring, count=1)
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(xmlwithoutns)
value = tree.findall("properties/dependency-version")[0].text
```