# XML parse does not show nodes

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

t = """<collection xmlns:y="http://tail-f.com/ns/rest">
  <appliance xmlns="http://networks.com/vnms/nms">
    <uuid>088fbb70-40d1-4aaf-8ea3-590fd8238828</uuid>
    <name>SRVDHCPE1</name>
    <num-cpus>0</num-cpus>
    <memory-size>0</memory-size>
    <num-nics>4</num-nics>
  </appliance>
  <appliance xmlns="http://networks.com/vnms/nms">
    <uuid>088fbb70-40d1-4aaf-8ea3-590fd8238828</uuid>
    <name>SRVDHCPE2</name>
    <num-cpus>0</num-cpus>
    <memory-size>0</memory-size>
    <num-nics>4</num-nics>
  </appliance>
</collection>"""


dom = ElementTree.fromstring(t)
    for n in dom.findall("collection/appliance/name"):
        print(n.text)
```

Looking for all the names but it does not show. What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing text from XML node in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52847343/parsing-text-from-xml-node-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to namespace your selectors:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element

t = """<collection xmlns:y="http://tail-f.com/ns/rest">
  <appliance xmlns="http://versa-networks.com/vnms/nms">
    <uuid>088fbb70-40d1-4aaf-8ea3-590fd8238828</uuid>
    <name>SRVDHCPE1</name>
    <num-cpus>0</num-cpus>
    <memory-size>0</memory-size>
    <num-nics>4</num-nics>
  </appliance>
  <appliance xmlns="http://versa-networks.com/vnms/nms">
    <uuid>088fbb70-40d1-4aaf-8ea3-590fd8238828</uuid>
    <name>SRVDHCPE2</name>
    <num-cpus>0</num-cpus>
    <memory-size>0</memory-size>
    <num-nics>4</num-nics>
  </appliance>
</collection>"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dom: Element = ElementTree.fromstring(t)
    namespaces = {'n': 'http://versa-networks.com/vnms/nms'}
    for name in dom.findall("./n:appliance/n:name", namespaces=namespaces):
        print(name.text)
```

which prints:

```
SRVDHCPE1
SRVDHCPE2
```

For reference:
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces

Answer (score 1):

You case definitely related to [*Parsing XML with Namespaces*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces):

```
dom = ET.fromstring(t)
ns = {'rest': 'http://tail-f.com/ns/rest','nms': 'http://versa-networks.com/vnms/nms'}
for n in dom.findall("nms:appliance/nms:name", ns):
    print(n.text)
```

The output:

```
SRVDHCPE1
SRVDHCPE2
```